# Manjaro/Arch: Disabling IRQ #31 (Thinkpad X1 7th)

Tags: irq

I've stumbled upon the beforementioned error (disabling IRQ #31) during boot and have tried to resolve it by trying to find out what caused the interrupt.
Running `lspci -v | grep 31` gives no result and a `cat /proc/interrupts | grep 31` returns:

```
  31:          0          0          0          0     100000          0          0          0   IO-APIC   31-fasteoi   tpm0
 122:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 3162112-edge      pciehp
 131:          0          0          0          0          0          0       4780          0   PCI-MSI 1572871-edge      nvme0q7
 136:          0          0          0          0          0          0        377          0   PCI-MSI 520192-edge      enp0s31f6
 160:          0          0          1          0          0          0       1260          0   PCI-MSI 333831-edge      iwlwifi: queue 7
 RES:      25967      11451      13108       4439       3441       4165       4926       4203   Rescheduling interrupts
```

How should I proceed knowing that it maybe has to do something with `IO-APIC 31-fasteoi tpm0`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on my Lenovo L390 (running Fedora 31). In my case the issue reproduced by waking up the laptop when in suspension mode.

For me the issue was resolved (or worked around) by disabling the Trusted Platform Module in the BIOS.